# ROUND TSQL - .5 not rounding up

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sum, rounding

In my select statement I have the following case statement which I need to round to 0 decimal places to return an INT:

```
SELECT 
        ReportingDate
    ,   PortfolioID
    ,   PortfolioNme
    ,   '16'                                                                AS [Rank]
    ,   'Average credit rating'                                             AS Rating
    ,   ROUND(SUM((Percentage * CASE
                                    WHEN WT.IssueType1 IN ('050','110') THEN 15.5
                                    ELSE xref.internal_value2
                                END ))/SUM(Percentage),0)   AS [Weight]

FROM @WorktableSA as WT

    LEFT OUTER JOIN DP_CrossReference AS xref
        ON xref.internal_value = WT.Rating
        AND xref.codeset_type_id = 10013
        AND xref.originator_id = 'KurtosysExtract'          

GROUP BY    WT.ReportingDate
        ,   WT.PortfolioID
        ,   WT.PortfolioNme


ORDER BY    WT.ReportingDate
        ,   WT.PortfolioID
```

There is one particular result returned which isn't correct.  The value it returns in the SUM before the ROUND is 15.5.  But the ROUND is returning a value of 15, when I'm expecting this to be rounded up to 16.

To give some insight into the data types, Percentage is a FLOAT and internal_value2 is an NVARCHAR which holds a mixture of INT (1,2,3) and one decimal (15.5).

I've tried amending all the values to be floats and I still get 15.  I've even done the following and it returns 16:

```
SELECT ROUND(15.5,0)
```

Any help in trying to test an alternative would be much appreciated because I'm now out of ideas?

Comment: It's hard to be sure without test data, but I think you don't get precisely 15.5, you have something like 15.4999. Try using decimal instead of float and/or round the values before the division.

Comment: As you posted, `select ROUND(15.5,0)` returns 16. If you get 15, it means your input is *not* equal to 15.5 but some other value. It may be formatted as such for display purposes but that doesn't mean the result of the division is actually equal to 15.5. In fact, using a FLOAT instead of NUMERIC almost guarantees rounding errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With round function all is ok, `SELECT ROUND(15.5,0)` will return `16`

But, for example, if required to round values starting from `0.39` up to `1` (as in your example can be `15.49` up to `16`) then use method below

```
DECLARE @val AS FLOAT = 15.49

SELECT ( CASE WHEN @val - CONVERT(INT, @val) >= 0.49
                    THEN CEILING(@val)
              ELSE ROUND(@val, 0)  END )   AS NewVal
```

this variant also applicable, but since 2012 version

```
SELECT IIF( @val - CONVERT(INT, @val) >= 0.49, CEILING(@val), ROUND(@val, 0))  AS NewVal
```

So your final query should be like this:

```
SELECT T.ReportingDate
      ,T.PortfolioID
      ,T.PortfolioNme
      ,T.[Rank]
      ,T.Rating
      ,(CASE    WHEN T.[Weight] - CONVERT(INT, T.[Weight]) >= 0.49
                THEN CEILING(T.[Weight])
                ELSE ROUND(T.[Weight], 0) END) AS [Weight]
FROM (   SELECT ReportingDate
               ,PortfolioID
               ,PortfolioNme
               ,'16' AS [Rank]
               ,'Average credit rating' AS Rating
               ,ROUND(SUM((Percentage * CASE WHEN WT.IssueType1 IN ('050','110')
                                             THEN 15.5
                                             ELSE xref.internal_value2 END)) 
                        / SUM(Percentage), 0) AS [Weight]
         FROM @WorktableSA AS WT
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN DP_CrossReference AS xref 
                            ON xref.internal_value = WT.Rating
                                AND xref.codeset_type_id = 10013
                                AND xref.originator_id = 'KurtosysExtract'
        GROUP BY WT.ReportingDate
                ,WT.PortfolioID
                ,WT.PortfolioNme
    ) AS T
ORDER BY T.ReportingDate
        ,T.PortfolioID
```

---

2. If you faced with a problem like this `SELECT ROUND(15.49999,0)` then this method will help you

   ```
   DECLARE @val AS FLOAT = 15.49999

   SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,1),@val),0)
   ```

which will return `16`

So, your final query should be like this

```
SELECT 
        ReportingDate
    ,   PortfolioID
    ,   PortfolioNme
    ,   '16'                                                                AS [Rank]
    ,   'Average credit rating'                                             AS Rating
    ,   ROUND(CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,1),SUM((Percentage * CASE
                                    WHEN WT.IssueType1 IN ('050','110') THEN 15.5
                                    ELSE xref.internal_value2
                                END ))/SUM(Percentage)),0)   AS [Weight]

FROM @WorktableSA as WT

    LEFT OUTER JOIN DP_CrossReference AS xref
        ON xref.internal_value = WT.Rating
        AND xref.codeset_type_id = 10013
        AND xref.originator_id = 'KurtosysExtract'          

GROUP BY    WT.ReportingDate
        ,   WT.PortfolioID
        ,   WT.PortfolioNme
```

Comment: This won't help at all because ROUND isn't broken. the input value isn't 15.5, it's a FLOAT generated as a result of division of FLOAT numbers that is formatted as `15.5` for display

Comment: Thanks for the response @Vasily, however I'm still getting the result of 15, even with your script above.  What do you think maybe causing this?  Is it a datatype issue or something from my WorktableSA table or from the DP_CrossReference?  Makes no sense at the moment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that with `round` works fine, value in `case` function can be whatever you want, I can write 0.49 or 0.39 if you don't like 0.5, it just an example of the solution how to get nearest `INT` for those who required it.

Comment: @chrissyp please take a look at my updated post, now I think all is clear for you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug.

Try this and it will not work as expected:

```
declare @dd float

select @dd = 375.45
select @dd,ROUND(@dd,1)
```

the result is

```
375.45  375.4
```